# Exclude a field from validation upon submission in django view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

This is my model

```
class Food: 
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="foods"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This is my form

```
class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        choices=CHOICES required=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = (
            "name",
            "location",
            "category"
        )
```

Upon update, I don't need to save the location. I just need it in the filtering of the category since it depends on it, but I don't have to save it. upon submission for the update, it throws the error `'Food' object has no attribute 'location'`. Is there any way I can exclude this field upon submission?

This is my view

```
 class FoodUpdateView(BaseUpdateView):

    form_class = forms.FoodForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Food.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Your `Food` model has no `location` field, so the error says it does not know where to save the `location` to.

Comment: I don't have to save the `location` value. I just need it in filtering the `category` on the template view. But I don't have to save it.

Comment: then you should remove it from the form, and likely use JavaScript to do the filtering at the frontend side.

Comment: Yes im currently using the javascript already. The category will change everytime the location changes. The location option will be coming from a different model list. Is there anyway i can load it in form?

Comment: yes take a look for example at [**`django-selectable`**](https://github.com/mlavin/django-selectable). This works with a lookup where it will query the database if the user types in some characters.